# Find the smallest group of integers that has a certain mean

Tags: arithmetic

The two integers 1, 2 have the mean 1.5. It's actually the fewest number of integers that has this mean; 0, 1, 2, 3, also has the mean 1.5, but there are four integers now instead of two.

How can I find a smallest group of numbers that has a certain mean?

For example, if I want the mean 5.3333, the algorithm should inform me that 5,5,6, has this mean.

Comment: If the given mean is $\frac{p}{q}$ with coprime integers $p,q$ and $q>0$ , then the smallest number of numbers we need is $q$.